# Wordpress: I cannot close PrettyPhoto lightbox

Tags: jquery, wordpress, prettyphoto

I use the PrettyPhoto plugin in Wordpress. When I click on a photo a fancybox pops up with an embedded youtube video. When I click on the X in the bottom right corner nothing happens - the box does not close. It only closes when I click outside the box.

Anyone can tell me how to solve this problem?

I have already had a look into my console: there is no Javascript error message or whatsoever.

Comment: Wordpress has its own Stack site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think You need to create a function on your "parent" page that closes the lightbox. Then call your function from the lightbox when the close button is clicked.

Comment: @amiya thank you for your hint, but I have no clue how to achieve that: could you suggest a code please?

Comment: @KentMiller which theme are you using ? WooThemes ? Probably

Comment: @Amiya I use the twentytwelve theme with my individual template

Comment: okay . Please check http://bowesales.com/technical-help/how-to-integrate-prettyphoto-with-your-wordpress-theme/ & http://fearlessflyer.com/how-to-add-lightbox-to-wp-without-plugin/ I hope it helps you

Comment: @Diodeus wordpress.stackexchange.com is not for plugin discussion/help http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3740

Comment: @amiya  thank you, but i use it as a plugin. I just tried to manually have the box closed when you click on the "X" with the following code, but it doesn't work: jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  
  jQuery('.pp_close').click(function() {
   
   jQuery('.pp_picholder').fadeOut();
   jQuery('.movieContainer').fadeOut();
   
  });
  
})